# Integrating Angular 2.0 inside Angular 1.x - upgrade module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am trying to integrate an Angular 2.0 component inside an Angular 1.x app (for playing / learning propose...)

Now, I see that it can be done by looking at the Angular2 [upgrade module](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/upgrade/test/integration_spec.ts):

```
    import {Component, View, Inject, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/angular2';
    import {createUpgradeModule, UpgradeModule} from 'upgrade/upgrade';

    export function main() {
      describe('upgrade: ng1 to ng2', () => {
        it('should have angular 1 loaded', () => expect(angular.version.major).toBe(1));

        it('should instantiate ng2 in ng1 template and project content',
           inject([AsyncTestCompleter], (async) => {
             var Ng2 = Component({selector: 'ng2'})
                           .View({template: `{{ 'NG2' }}(<ng-content></ng-content>)`})
                           .Class({constructor: function() {}});

             var element = html("<div>{{ 'ng1[' }}<ng2>~{{ 'ng-content' }}~</ng2>{{ ']' }}</div>");

             var upgradeModule: UpgradeModule = createUpgradeModule();
             upgradeModule.importNg2Component(Ng2);
             upgradeModule.bootstrap(element).ready(() => {
               expect(document.body.textContent).toEqual("ng1[NG2(~ng-content~)]");
               async.done();
             });
           }));
... continue tests here  ...
```

I created an Angular 1.x app with Typescript + SystemJS + JSPM and installed Angular 2.0 using `jspm install angular2`

Now, I can import Angular2 using `import {Component} from 'angular2/angular2'` (for example), but I cannot find the upgrade module anywhere in Angular2's code (I wanted to do `import {createUpgradeModule, UpgradeModule} from 'upgrade/upgrade'`, similar to what I found in the tests).

Is it in a separate package? Should I install it manually?

**EDIT**

The solution (for now), should be:

1. Use a custom build, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33395962/916450)
2. Take the actual module to you project and import it (this was my preferred solution)

   Edit 22.11.15:

As of alpha 46 the upgrade module is public. No need for any more hacks in order to use it!

Comment: I think you may be looking for [this line](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/test-main.js#L18). I can't find that path in my projects tho, so maybe it's not being distributed or so. But what you can do is fork angular repo, build it and you'll find that dir so you can copy & paste it into your project.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some POC work around this and here is a working approach:

The key to this is the upgradeAdaptor

```
import {bootstrap,UpgradeAdapter} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {SomeA2Component} from './some/path';

declare var angular:any;

var adapter: UpgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter();
angular.module('app').directive('SomeA2Component', adapter.downgradeNg2Component(MyA2Component));
adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```

I also have a working example here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/upgrading-angular-1.x-to-2.0

Comment: Thanks. As of alpha 46 upgrade module is public and no need for workarounds. Nice blog post!