# Angular 2.0 - custom build/ import and use an "on develop" module

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to play with integrating Angular 2.0 components inside an Angular 1.X project, using the [upgrade module](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/upgrade).

I figured out that this module is [not public/available for import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125045/integrating-angular-2-0-inside-angular-1-x-upgrade-module) in Alpha 44.

I was wondering how can I build Angular2 locally + export this module so I'll be able to import it on my local project? (I guess I should dig inside their gulp/build in order to figure this out)

Comment: See this [article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/10/24/upgrading-apps-to-angular-2-using-ngupgrade.html). At the moment I wrote the comment in your other question I didn't know about this article and I haven't tried ngUpgrade either, so I didn't dig into it.

Comment: I know this article. He's saying that you cannot use this module for now (it is not public, yet). I was looking for a way to add it to the build locally on my env...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 18/11/2015**

Since alpha 46 `ngUpgrade` is already available, so the below steps are no longer necessary.

**Update 30/10/2015**

As of today the commit referenced in the original answer was merged to the [main repository](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/d545275e75c07623c0504e3d6e8285c2f88e0592). So you can skip some of those steps and build it following the [Developer guide](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md).

**Original answer**

Well, I found a way. First note that Misko commited [ngUpgrade to angular2's main repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/4931) but it's still not merged, so these few steps will change in a short time, I think.

Steps :

- Clone [Misko's repo](https://github.com/mhevery/angular)
- Change to `imports` branch

```
sudo git checkout imports
```

- Install dependencies

```
npm install
```

- Build

```
// This will build only the js files
$(npm bin)/gulp build.js  

// or both js and dart files
//$(npm bin)/gulp build
```

After all these steps you'll have the bundles under

```
angular/dist/js/bundle
```

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QVVNK2?p=preview) with the minified bundle added manually.

I hope this is what you are looking for :)

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for! I did not try to play with it, yet, but it seems to work great.